# making the bot resend embeds with all it's attributes

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so the idea for the bot is to send an embed to a channel, then resend it with all the embed's attributes but with a new footer.

but the problem i'm running into right now is the new embed has to have the same attributes or less than the old embed to not raise an exception. e.g. **author, image,  url**.

this is the code i'm testing with:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  global test_channel, bot_command_channel, cu_free_games_channel
  test_channel = bot.get_channel(868816978293452841)
  bot_command_channel = bot.get_channel(808734570283139162)
  cu_free_games_channel = bot.get_channel(873018877020373043)

  print('bot is ready')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):


  if message.content.startswith('!test'):
    embed_old = discord.Embed(
      title= '''this is the title''', 
      description= '''this is the description''', 
      color= discord.Color.red(),
      # url= '''https://www.google.com/'''
      )
    embed_old.set_footer(text='old footer')
    await bot_command_channel.send(embed=embed_old)


  if message.channel == bot_command_channel:
    if not len(message.embeds):
      return
    else:
      embed_content_in_dict = message.embeds[0].to_dict()
      print(embed_content_in_dict) #prints out the embed's content

      for embed in embed_content_in_dict:
        embed_new = discord.Embed(
          title= embed_content_in_dict["title"],
          type= embed_content_in_dict["type"],
          description= embed_content_in_dict["description"],
          url = embed_content_in_dict["url"], # if the URL in embed_old is commented out, it throws an exception
          )
        embed_new.set_footer(text='new footer')
        await test_channel.send(embed=embed_new)
        return


  

bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

this is what prints in the console:

```
bot is ready

{'footer': {'text': 'old footer'}, 'color': 15158332, 'type': 'rich', 'description': 'this is the description', 'title': 'this is the title'}

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 47, in on_message
    url = embed_content_in_dict["url"], # if the URL in embed_old is commented out, it throws an exception
KeyError: 'url'
```

someone suggested that i use `embed_content_in_dict.get('url')` but this still raises an exception (given it's not a real one and only triggers in discord.py 1.7 and not 1.6)
this is the error i get if i use `.get('url')` :

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 50, in on_message
    await test_channel.send(embed=embed_new)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1065, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed,
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.url: Scheme "none" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').
```

so my question is how can i make the bot resends the original embed with all it's attributes without raising an exception on the latest version?

Comment: why overcomplicating the code so much? You can re-send an embed and change the footer with just three lines: `for em in message.embeds: em.set_footer(text="foo"); await message.channel.send(embed=em)`

Comment: HOLY **** HOLY **** thank you so much, i feel so dumb coz i've been down this rabbit hole for ages and was just adding variables that can go wrong to the code rather than simplifying the problem, i can't thank you enough

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Please write an answer with this, and `omar` please accept it, to mark the question as answered for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resend an embed and change it's footer (and/or any other attribute) with just three lines:

```py
for embed in message.embeds:
    embed.set_footer(text="whatever")
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```